# Force newly opened files to open in existing window of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VS Code open and am actively using it. If I double-click the icon of a file that VS Code is configured to be the default program for, it opens as a new tab in the current window.

However, when I open a file from the command line, this does not occur. Instead it opens a new window.

The command I am using is `code <filepath>`.
`which code` gives `/usr/local/bin/code`, if it is helpful.

Is there a way to configure it to open as a new tab in the already-open window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following option:

```
-r --reuse-window                          Force to open a file or folder in
                                             an already opened window.
```

So the command you would use would be:

```
code -r <filepath>
```

I just found this option by typing `code --help` - I would suggest doing this in the future to check the available options and see if one does what you want.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work for me, thanks though. `code -r <filepath>` still opens it in a new window. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it. I'm on a mac for what it's worth. There is as far as I can tell only one instance of VS Code installed - certainly only one listed in Applications.

Comment: Is your VS Code installation using the latest version?

Comment: Also, please confirm that `window.openFilesInNewWindow` and `window.openWithoutArgumentsInNewWindow` are set to `off` in your settings.

Comment: Both are set to `off`. I am on version 1.74, which appears to be latest. I wish I could add something helpful but I really have no idea what's causing this.

Comment: However, just now I deleted the old dock icon and dragged the newly opened window instance into the dock where the old one was.....and now everything opens in the same window.  I think I've done this before and the issue eventually came back somehow.

Comment: That sounds a bit buggy... it could possibly be a bug on MacOS only? I suggest opening an issue on their Github repo, giving as much detail about your system and maybe linking to this question here - I can't reproduce the issue on a Windows or Linux machine (don't have access to a Mac).

Similar issues to what you're having have been opened in the past, but they were on much older versions (on Windows also) and should have been patched by now. All your settings appear to be correct (even if they weren't, the `-r` option should override it).

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem, sorry we couldn't work out the problem! If you do manage to solve it elsewhere, please link it as an answer here :)

Answer (score 1):

In MacOS, the sugessted solution doesn't work for folders, only files.

In macOS Sonoma:
*System Settings > Desktop & Dock > Windows -> Prefer tabs when opening documents = Always*

This makes sure that when i run `code .` in a folder it will open as a new tab in vscode.